# How to share add-ons between apps in different stages of heroku pipelines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I recently took over a rails project in Heroku from someone else. I set up Heroku pipelines and synced it with my Github repository. When my apps are in the "review" stage, Heroku automatically gives them the same addons as the original app, which is in "Production".

However, when I add an app from the Github master branch to "Staging", none of the addons are shared. How can I get Heroku to treat my Staging app the same way it treats the Review apps?

Answer (score 0):

This is down to your `app.json` that will be in the root of your project. PR apps are built from the definition in that file, if you look at yours you'll probably find a bunch of addons listed.

Typically though, staging isn't destroyed/recreated like PR apps - you could create an empty app for staging though and then from the pipeline interface, choose 'Deploy a branch' on the new app to trigger a deployment of your chosen branch - that would then make it build from the app.json definition.